# how do i resolve this error i keep getting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

1 of 1 unhandled error

`Server Error`
`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Module.isRTL

```
node_modules\bootstrap\js\dist\util\index.js (188:50)
isRTL
node_modules\bootstrap\js\dist\dropdown.js (72:33)
factory
node_modules\bootstrap\js\dist\dropdown.js (7:82)
eval
node_modules\bootstrap\js\dist\dropdown.js (10:3)
(rsc)/./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js
file:///C:/Users/PC/Documents/Library%20Apps/library/.next/server/app/page.js (1101:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/PC/Documents/Library%20Apps/library/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/Components/Nav.js (8:84)
(rsc)/./app/Components/Nav.js
file:///C:/Users/PC/Documents/Library%20Apps/library/.next/server/app/page.js (997:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/PC/Documents/Library%20Apps/library/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/Components/Home.js (8:62)

import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'

export default function Nav(){
    return(
```

Comment: Please use code formatting, it is hard to read the error when dumped in plain text.

Comment: please use three backticks (` ` `) with no spaces to format your code when posting on Stack overflow

Comment: @Winston -  when posting on SO, please always include: The environment language (like React, NextJS, etc), the versions of which libraries you are using. if this is server or client code, etc. It seem from this stacktrace you have a React app that is rendering a react server component and trying to look for `document`. I think that's your problem -- RSC doesn't have access to the browser document. nevertheless, please re-post with languages, versions of those languages, and specify whether or not this is a server component.

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself tells you *what* is the problem: the isRTL module is trying to access the global `document` object, but that object doesn't exist.

As for why this is happening, that's hard to determine because it's specific to your project. It looks like you're using Next.js which I'm guessing has server rendered elements. My initial suspicion is that you're running client-side code in a server-side step, where there isn't a concept of a document object.

Since the error happens in isRTL which is a Bootstrap thing, it's likely that whatever you're doing incorrectly is somewhere else upstream, and isRTL is just the symptom you actually see. Looking at the stack trace, it seems like you're calling some dropdown stuff inside a file called server/app/page.js. I don't know enough about Next.js to tell you if what you're doing *should* be working, but for the next step in your troubleshooting, I'd look there to see if your code is actually running where it should be.

If it turns out that you *are* using client-side code in a server-side environment, there are two ways to go about it:

1. You might be thinking about the problem wrong. Keep client side code on the client side.
2. Conditionally execute the code only when you know you're running on the client side. You can do that with something like:

```
if(typeof document != 'undefined'){
// ... your client side code
}
```

Hopefully this will get you on the right track to finding your answer!